# Expanding GROUP BY query into existing PDO get query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my problem, I am followed a tutorial on youtube on using PDO as query, more like object oriented php query. I am trying to expand the functionality of the `get()` function. This main `get()` and `action` is the extension of the function that can only can get parameter `WHERE`. Here is the code :

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if (count($where) === 3) { // make sure 3 array
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<='); // available operators

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator       = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

I am trying to expand the `GROUP BY` query in this function. Here is my try so far. But I get this error on the page **`count()`**

`Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object` in this function

```
// Find user and return first found
public function find($user = null) {
    if ($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'user_id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('user', array($field, '=', $user));

        **if ($data->count()) {**
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

The query that I am doing:

`DB::getInstance()->get('table', array('date', '=', $date_sort), array('car_id'));`

Here is what I have done so far :

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array(), $group = array()) {
    if (count($where) === 3) { // make sure 3 array
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<='); // available operators

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        $g_field    = $group[0];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ? GROUP BY {$g_field}";

            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//$user = DB::getInstance()->get('user', array('username', '=', 'sanbrons'));
public function get($table, $where, $group = null) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where, $group);
}
```

Comment: Looks awful. I'd stop following that tutorial immediately

Comment: awful but what I see php in object oriented is the future dynamic php.

Comment: My judgement has nothing to do with OOP or PHP. This is just plain bad code. It's terribly unreadable and from what I can tell, does not use parameter binding or bothers to sanitise query values. These are basic tenants of relational database application programming.

Comment: **This set of functions has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.** Don't let them to fool you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following two statements and please tell me, on which one you can tell what the heck it is doing at all?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = ? GROUP BY car_id

get('table', array('date', '=', $date_sort), array('car_id'));
```

Look, you are trying to save yourself a word or two. **Do you really think it worth to spoil whole great SQL experience for such a saving?**

Get rid of this useless "tutorial". It is written by someone who have not a slightest clue neither on SQL, nor on PDO, nor especially on OOP. There is actually *nothing* object-oriented about this query. If you want a **query builder**, or if you want to learn how to write one - **you need to make yourself familiar with an existing one first.** Fetch yourself a popular **framework** and learn how to use its query builder.

Comment: it is a dynamic ways of getting information from database. And the guy who did the tutorial is from phpacademy at Youtube. I followed everything that they taught and it is worth. Don't tell me that the pdo isn't the future of dynamic php. I just eager to try out the pdo instead of the traditional MYSQLI.

1st :
Get all information in `table` `WHERE` date is equal to some variable array which is encode in the `get()` and `GROUP BY` `car_id`

2nd :
Calling of function `get()` with passing first parameter `table`, second parameter `array of WHERE` and third parameter `array of GROUP BY`.

Comment: This terrible stuff has nothing to do with PDO actually. *If* you were learned *anything* useful from this ignorant "tutorial", you would know that first example can be run with PDO all right, without the need of any of these "functions". All right, if you want to torture yourself with this ignorant tutorial further - it is up to you.

Comment: I have already make myself familiar with the existing MYSQLI querying. and I am trying to learn myself with the new ways of PDO querying. I have not problem with the MYSQLI, but learning new ways isn't forbidden?

Comment: Ok, I will take that as advice. Of course you did not see the PDO here because I did not show you, it was in the other lines, the contructor function. Do you think this guy's tutorial is useless? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris I haven't seen the video yet, but **yes**

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris Yes, I told you it from the beginning. It is useless. And it has nothing to do with PDO: in fact, one can use any driver with this awful set of functions. It has nothing to do with OOP either: OOP is a use of classes, not functions with messy arguments.

Comment: And worst part: this guy on youtube have no clue on **SQL**. And your current problem is a direct consequence of this. In fact, SQL is far more complex language than he thinks. And it cannot be fit in just one function call. There are much more operators beside GROUP BY. People who invented SQL were not such fools as you think. It was invented for a reason.  If someone have fancy to call themselves "academy" that doesn't make them knowledgeable. Don't be such naive.

Comment: @Phil :The fact that you have to see what an expert in php like him able teaches beginners like me. I understood what he taught in his tutorial, very simple.

Comment: @YourCommonSense : Well yea maybe I misunderstood here. This is a Database class if you wanna know. I called the DB class and it's function. Thank you for advising.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I really appreciate your advices. Thank you. :) I'll look forward for other alternative then.

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris The tutorial is teaching you nothing but bad habits (and yes, I have watched the video now). I don't even know where to begin on explaining just how bad this is

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris if you want to look at the *real* OOP, just browse examples here: http://laravel.com/docs/queries Note the REAL OOP syntax and note that all the vital key words that can let you tell you what the heck this variable is for - a group by or where or order by? - are all retained in place - so, when reading this code you can tell which SQL is behind it. While with your functions you can't

Comment: @Phil if you say it is bad, then where should I learn? The best free tutorial I can find now is their channel. You have recommendation perhaps?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Okay. I will looked up for that :) Thank you.

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris I'll repeat what I said earlier (but with a working link this time), start here ~ http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php